# Spark AnalysisException while reading a column from a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe defined as follows

```
val structDfTrace = structDfOrigin
        .withColumnRenamed("pos", "_pos")
        .withColumn(CommonFields.REQUEST_ENTRY_NO, col("_pos").cast(LongType) + 1)
        .transform(getKafkaHeaderData)
        .select(CommonFields.SUB_ACCOUNT_ID, CommonFields.Z_ID, CommonFields.TENANT_ID, CommonFields.OBJECT_NAME, CommonFields.DATA_SOURCE,
          CommonFields.INTERNAL_ZONE_ID, CommonFields.SYSTEM_ID, CommonFields.ENTITY_VERSION, CommonFields.SAP_PASSPORT, CommonFields.CORRELATION_ID,
          CommonFields.REQUEST_TRACE_ID, CommonFields.REQUEST_ENTRY_NO, CommonFields.REQUEST_ENTRY_COUNT, "col.*")
```

I am trying to extract one column from the dataframe using a statement as follows:

```
      val subAccountId = structDfTrace.select(CommonFields.SUB_ACCOUNT_ID).collectAsList().get(0).toString()
      logger.warn("Sub Account Id: "+subAccountId)

But I get an error as shown: 
  org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();
```

Is there a way I can extract the CommonFields.SUB_ACCOUNT_ID column from the dataframe?

Thanks,
Prabal